# Handle Data returned by POST request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP script - it returns a file like this after POSTing to it with the help of $.post() using jQuery.

```
13.0519 77.5416
13.028 77.5409
12.9787 77.5724
12.9317 77.6227
```

How do I go through the lines of data returned in the $.post().done(function(data){}) in Javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split returned text by newline character and then loop over resulting array of lines, probably splitting one more time by space to get array of numbers:

```
$.post(/*...*/).done(function(data) {
    var lines = data.split(/\n/);
    lines.forEach(function(line) {
        console.log(line.split(' '));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have PHP return JSON (with an array of these).

If not possible, however, then you can get the string and split it on new lines, to achieve a similar effect. Something along the lines of

```
var arrayOfResults = postData.split("\n");
```

Then just iterate and do whatever is needed.